# django reset contenttypes mismatch

Tags: python, mysql, django

Have deleted my database.

Have run SyncDb.

Trying to load from dump ..-python manage.py loaddata dump.json.

Get- "<1062 Duplicate entry '' for key.."

Have run "python manage.py reset contentypes"

But get-

```
 Error: Error: contenttypes couldn't be reset. Possible reasons:
  * The database isn't running or isn't configured correctly.
  * At least one of the database tables doesn't exist.
  * The SQL was invalid.
Hint: Look at the output of 'django-admin.py sqlreset contenttypes'. That's the SQL this command wasn't able to run.
The full error: (1217, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails')
```

Have try to run:

> > > from django.core import management
> > >
> > > management.call_command("flush", verbosity=, interactive=False)
> > >
> > > management.call_command("totally reset", "contenttypes", verbosity=, interactive=False)
> > >
> > > management.call_command("loaddata", "full_test_data.json", verbosity=)

But get- syntax error.

Have python 2.7. and Django 1.4

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `foreign_key_checks` false,

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # ...         
        'OPTIONS': {
            "init_command": "SET foreign_key_checks = 0;",
        },
    }
}
```

But you should definitely try to use the dumpdata command with the [--natural](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---natural) option to make sure there's no hardcoded content types in your fixtures.

Comment: Did not work unfortunately. Yes, next time I do a dumpdata I will use -natural. But now is it a little bit to late to do it :-(